# Is it possible to get all the information like note and velocity from a manually recorded audio but converted into midi format?

Tags: audio, midi

As we can obtain all the information conveniently from a midi file, is it possible to obtain these info from recorded audio which was not originally midi but is converted to midi ?

Comment: Are you asking how to do the conversion, or if the resulting MIDI files differ?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289091/record-in-midi-format-with-usb-mic/37293519#37293519